How to import volley in Android Studio Iguana
I am trying to add volley to my gradle dependencies and import it into my MainActivity.class. As implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1" is not being recognised and import com.android.volley.Request as well in Android Studio Iguana. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
build.gradle.kts
dependencies {
implementation(libs.android.volley)
}

MainActivity.class
import com.android,volley.Request


Use version 1.2.1 that is the latest version and is available in Maven Central and Google repo https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.volley/volley/1.2.1
